# Bug fix in a matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, unity-game-engine, file-io, io

I am doing a unity project and I use `mapMatrix`(matrix of chars) as a map tool to tell which `gameObject` to instantiate as an environment.
Firstly, I call function `populateMapMatrix` and `writeTextFile` to create a txt file with content of a matrix. But now, I need to read from that file into a matrix and then instantiate the environment. I debugged the project and some elements of matrix get '\n' even if I have a way of dealing with that `chars`. Can someone help me?
Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class EnviromentBuilder : MonoBehaviour {

    const int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 50;
    const int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 50;
    const char GRASS_MATRIX_FIELD = 'G';
    const char TREE_MATRIX_FIELD = 'T';

    const string pathToFile = "C:\\Users\\Darko\\Desktop\\Unity\\WAR GAME\\enviromentMapMatrix.txt";

    public char[,] mapMatrix;

    public GameObject grass;
    public GameObject tree;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {       
        mapMatrix = new char[NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];

        //populateMapMatrix ();
        readTextFile();

        InstantiateEnviroment ();

        //writeTextFile ();
    }


    bool isGrassMatrixField(int i, int j)
    {
        return mapMatrix [i, j] == GRASS_MATRIX_FIELD ? true : false; 
    }


    bool isTreeMatrixField(int i, int j)
    {
        return mapMatrix [i, j] == TREE_MATRIX_FIELD ? true : false;
    }


    void populateMapMatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; j++) 
            {

                mapMatrix[i,j] = 'G';

                if (i > 28 && i < 45 && j > 20 && j < 38) {
                    mapMatrix[i,j] = 'T';
                }

            }
    }


    void InstatiateGrassField(int i, int j)
    {
        if (isGrassMatrixField(i,j))
        {
            Instantiate (grass, new Vector3 (i, 0, j), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }


    void InstantiateTreeField(int i, int j)
    {
        if (isTreeMatrixField(i,j)) {
            Instantiate (tree, new Vector3 (i, 0, j), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }


    void InstantiateEnviroment()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; j++) 
            {
                //Instantiate a grass prefab
                InstatiateGrassField(i, j);
                //Instantiate a tree prefab
                InstantiateTreeField(i, j);
            }
    }

    void writeTextFile()
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter (pathToFile))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; j++)
                {
                    streamWriter.Write (mapMatrix [i, j]);

                    //streamWriter.Write (' ');
                }

                streamWriter.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }

    void readTextFile()
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(pathToFile))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; j++) 
                {
                    char karakter = (char)streamReader.Read ();
                    if (karakter == '\n')
                    {
                        karakter = (char)streamReader.Read ();
                    }

                    mapMatrix [i, j] = karakter;
                }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This goes wrong when two `\n` are in the file: `\n\n`. You'd better read the whole file `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` And remove all `\n` from it. _(replace with nothing)_

Comment: Don't forget that `streamWriter.WriteLine();` will also add a `\r`  _(return)_ So you might fix it with adding `if (karakter == '\r') { karakter =(char)streamReader.Read (); }`

Comment: Thanks. I solved it. I used StreamReader.ReadToEnd() and replaced \n and \r with nothing then converted string to matrix using indexes